# Column at the same time can't be equal a certain values (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
+------+----------+-------------+
| id   | category | category_id |
+------+----------+-------------+
|  1   | 2        | 12          |
|  2   | 1        | 12          |
|  3   | 3        | 54          |
|  4   | 3        | 17          |
|  5   | 2        | 14          |
+------+----------+-------------+
```

I nead to get the following:
when category = 2 : category_id != 12
i.e

```
+------+----------+-------------+
| id   | category | category_id |
+------+----------+-------------+
|  2   | 1        | 12          |
|  3   | 3        | 54          |
|  4   | 3        | 17          |
|  5   | 2        | 14          |
+------+----------+-------------+
```

This code does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `category`!=2 AND `category_id`!=12
```

Comment: What should the output look like in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `OR`:

```
select *
from `table`
where `category` != 2
    or `category_id` != 12
```

Which, as per [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), is same as:

```
select *
from `table`
where not (
        `category` = 2
        and `category_id` = 12
        )
```

which reads - *get all rows except when category is 2 and category_id is 12 in one row*

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot !